# I might be confused about std::set works. My code isn't working right

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, std

I'm making a plagiarism detection program. The finished product will compare two entire text documents sentence-by-sentence; at this point I'm just testing my algorithm for comparing to sentences and giving a number between 0 and 1 for how similar their words are.

I'll try to step through the code and show you what the problem is.

Directives and a function declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <set>

double sntnc_cmpr_qtnt(const std::vector<std::string>&, const std::vector<std::string>&);
```

The main takes two arrays of strings and puts them into vectors. I know this seems useless, but it's just for my testing purposes. I calculate the sentence comparison quotient between the two vectors of strings (which are supposed to be 2 sentences).

```
int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    std::string arr1[] = {"Yo", "dawg", "I", "heard", "you", "like", "functions", "so", "we", "put", "a", "function", "inside"};
    std::vector<std::string> str1, str2; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(std::string); ++i) 
        str1.push_back(arr1[i]);
    std::string arr2[] = {"Yo", "dawg", "I", "heard", "you", "like", "cars", "so", "we", "put", "a", "car", "inside"};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(std::string); ++i) 
        str2.push_back(arr2[i]);

    std::cout << sntnc_cmpr_qtnt(str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the sentence comparison quotient function. It counts the number of words in common between the 2 sentences.

Something is going wrong, though. My count ("cnt") is coming out to 158, which is obviously too high. I can't figure out why that is.

```
double sntnc_cmpr_qtnt(const std::vector<std::string>& s1, const std::vector<std::string>& s2) {
    // Place the words of sentences s1 and s2 each into seperate sets s1_set and s2_set:
    std::set<std::string> s1set, s2set; 
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); ++it) 
        s1set.insert(*it); 
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = s2.begin(); it != s2.end(); ++it) 
        s2set.insert(*it); 

    /* Compute the proportion of words in common between str1_set and str2_set, 
       multiped by 1 over 1 minus the squareroot of the size of the smaller set.
       This is the sentence comparison quotient that is returned.  */ 
    double cnt(0.0);
    for (std::set<std::string>::iterator it1 = s1set.begin(); it1 != s1set.end(); ++it1) { 
        for (std::set<std::string>::iterator it2 = s2set.begin(); it2 != s2set.end(); ++it2) { 
            if ((*it1).compare(*it2))
                cnt += 1.0;
        }
    }
    if (cnt == 0.0) { 
         return 0.0;
    } else {
        double minsz = (double)std::min(s1set.size(), s2set.size());
        return ((1-1/sqrt(minsz))*cnt/minsz);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at what [`string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) actually returns.

Comment: sizeof(std::string)=8 .... I'm pretty sure that's the size of a pointer to a string

Comment: Ah, I see, sbabbi. Whoops.

Comment: Could probably use `set_intersection` for this as well if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare two `std::string`'s using the `==` operator.

But you're also doing a lot more work than is necessary. A much faster solution would be to put all the words from the first list into the set, and save the set's size. Then put all the words from the second list into the set. The difference between the final set size and the saved size is the number of words in the second list which are not in the first list. (Unique words, that is.) Of course, the saved size is the number of unique words in the first list.

A similar computation would get you the number of unique words in the second list, and the number of words in the first list not in the second list.

The total execution time is roughly proportional to the total number of words (actually, it's `n log u` where `u` is the number of unique words), whereas your solution is proportional to the product of the list sizes.

Comment: @user2967799 - then how will you compute `double minsz = (double)std::min(s1set.size(), s2set.size())`

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: the first size you grab on each pass through the vectors is the size of the appropriate set. maybe i should have been more explicit about that, although it seemed obvious.

Comment: @rici it was meant for the OP to think about :)  -- but I'm not sure I follow - he wants the number of unique words - not total words for his scoring

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum:Right, and the size of the set after you insert all the words in s1 (or s2, for the second case) is exactly that.

Comment: @rici - your solution only has one set - you optimized out s2 and only have s12 where s12 is the union of s1 and s2 - s1 size can be obtained by s12 size before inserting v2

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: The third paragraph suggests that you do the computation twice to get both values. I know that looks suboptimal but it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is here:

```
if ((*it1).compare(*it2))
         cnt += 1.0;
```

This will increment cnt if they are NOT equal - compare returns 0 for equality

Also you have a set - instead for doing the inner loop, just call find:

```
 for (std::set<std::string>::iterator it1 = s1set.begin(); it1 != s1set.end(); ++it1)
    { 
            if (s2set.find(*it1) != s2set.end())
            {
                cnt += 1.0;
            }
    }
```

And I have no idea why `cnt` should be double instead of int